# What is the meaning of "pipelined" in Java Streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

In the Java Stream API definition, it says "Stream API is used to process collections of objects. A stream is a sequence of objects that supports various methods which can be **pipelined** to produce the desired result".

In this definition what is the meaning of *pipelined*?

Comment: Well, this should be the same meaning as using "pipeline" in many other software products and approaches: you have some input which moves through the pipeline (a series of steps) and produces some ouput. Basically, a pipeline is a series of operations that can be concatenated, e.g. `map()`, `filter()`, `collect()` each take an object from the stream, process it and put it back into "the stream" (at least conceptually this can be thought of being the same stream).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas i am confused from many hours because java stream is little bit of hard for beginer

Comment: Yes, streams can be hard and thus if you are a beginner you should concentrate on the basics first and advance to streams only if you have a good grasp of the basic concepts. This is similar to other advanced topics such as UI, reflection or multi-threading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***pipelined :*** like the production line in a factory .  Operations (methods) are the employees , every employee (method/operation) do his job and pass the product to the next employees to do their works .

**Example :**

> ....filter(...).map(...).collect(...);

An employee will filter the stream , and pass the filtered elements to the next employee , the next will map the products ( replace the product with another thing ) , the last employee will collect the results and give us the final "collection" of products.

[image]

Comment: I think it is a good example, thanks.